# Controlling throttle valve with PWM and TIP120

Tags: pic, motor, dc, pwm, darlington

I'm trying to achieve [this](http://youtu.be/tUXB4cQ28zA). He's using a darlington transistor, so I started looking for an [appropriate circuit](http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-Arduino-with-TIP120-transistor-to-control-moto/). I've made that, with a TIP120, using a 1k4 resistor (instead of 1k) and a 1N4007 diode (instead of 1N4004). But I do not believe that those two changes should make too big of a difference. I use a PIC 18F4450 to generate the PWM signal.

However it seems to be low on current. Because it does creates a high pitch noise, but does not move. My 12V power supply can provide up to 20A so that should be enough (by far). I also tried different PWM frequencies, including the 500Hz value that is used in the YT video. I get different noise pitches, but again no movement.

If I connect the valve directly to the power supply it opens all the way, so the valve itself is also working fine.

What am I doing wrong/not seeing?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz3Y6r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you post a schematic?  PWM alone likely won't control this like you want, but need PID with position feedback.

Comment: I understand, it needs to become a closed loop system. But I though I get the thing moving first... Let me add a schematic, one moment

Comment: Use real grown-up symbols for electronic parts.  We shouldn't have to decipher the schematic to see the circuit.  This mess needs to be re-drawn.

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/28251/2191 ... Also, do you have two unconnected grounds there?

Comment: Well I got it moving allright... A simple oversight... I forgot (as you can see in the schematic) to wire the GND of the PIC to the GND of the driver circuit (TIP120 emitter).

For clarity I will redraw the schematic as soon as I can properly sit down for it and take the time. Until then, please hold your horses.

Comment: Shouldn't the diode go across the motor, rather than across the switch?

Comment: Your PSU may be 20A but the TIP120 is 5A max, and even then it'll be getting quite warm as it's a darlington. However, I don't think that's your issue, just issues down the line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As OP has noted in the comments, they forgot to connect the two grounds together.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMLUuJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Additionally, they have the diode in the wrong place. The correct place is directly across the two terminals of the motor.

Finally, to calculate the Collector Current, (5v Source - 1.4v* VBE Diode Drop) / 1400Ω = 0.00257 Amp or 2.57 mA. The TIP120 has a minimum hfe or gain of 1000, so 2.57mA * 1000 = 2.57 Amps at the collector. The motor show draw about 2.5A or less, at stall, ideally.

*(1.4v Diode Drop because this is a Darlington NPN Transistor)